# how to protect my app from share to another?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a cordova/phonegap android developer, currently I have some free app and now I have plan to publish the paid app in playstore. But only one can purchase and share it to his/her friends, so they can use without pay. How can I protect it? I refer many things in internet but I am not got any solution.

I found the following cordova plugin
https://github.com/mobilino/Phonegap-android-license-plugin . But I am getting signature random values, no one match with LICENSING & IN-APP BILLING key. Or how can I use this plugin.

```
AndroidLicensePlugin.check(
    function(data) { alert( JSON.stringify(data));},
    function(errorString) { alert("error: " + errorString);}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Merbin, Not sure if you found your answer but here is what I have done.

When I want to share an Android App that I am selling I go to Google Play Dev and create a promotional code list and provide one of those promo code to friends.

Here is the code I have used with that same plugin.

```
//---------------------------
//---------------------------
function LicCheck() {

    //Running HTTP vs. Native
    try {
        //Default none or error
        setLicKeyValue(Number(99));

        AndroidLicensePlugin.check(
            function (data) {
                licProcessJSON(data);
            },
            function (errorString) {
                console.log('LicCheck() ERROR ' + errorString);
                setLicKeyValue(99);
            }
        );
    }
    catch (err) {
        setLicKeyValue(99);
        console.log('LicCheck() - Error - default set to 99 (try later) ' + err)
    }
}
//---------------------------
//---------------------------
function licProcessJSON(data) {
    var appLicResponseCode = Number(1); //0:owns, 1:do not own

    //data = {
    //    responseCode: 0,
    //    signedData: "0|-123456798|de.mobilino....", // 6 fields of | delimitered data
    //    signature: "" // the BASE64 encoded signature from Google
    //};

    console.log('data.responseCode ' + data.responseCode);

    //They own the app
    if (data.responseCode === 0) {
        console.log('licProcessJSON() - Onwer True');
        setLicKeyValue(0);
        return;
    }

    //They do not own the app
    if (data.responseCode === 1) {
        console.log('licProcessJSON() - Onwer False');
        setLicKeyValue(1);
        return;
    }

    console.log('licProcessJSON() - No Data?');
    setLicKeyValue(99);
}
//---------------------------------
//---------------------------------
function setLicKeyValue(value) {
    localStorage.setItem(_licIndicator, Number(value));
}
```